# Can I use JasperReports like D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, jasper-reports

Can I use *JasperReports* like [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). *D3* js is a *JavasSript* lib to generate user interactive reports, for example user can use particular area in report [like](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2013/11/26/d3-minimap-pan-and-zoom-demo/)  .

Is *JasperReports* really support like these features?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like Jasper Reports supports this at the moment, but you could implement D3 support in a custom component as suggested [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/818723/how-create-custom-component-and-integrate-d3js-charts).