# How to integrate D3.js to jasper soft community version

Tags: d3.js

We have created Dashboards using D3.js. But we are not able to invoke D3.js scripts from jasperreport server(community version) using the jrxml file.

Please suggest if there is a way to invoke D3 js scripts from jasreport(community version).

Comment: duplicates this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347998/can-i-use-jasperreports-like-d3-js#

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's too late for you, and you have already found a solution, but in case someone else reads your question and they should be interested in the answer, I give you some information:

URLs of Jasper Community where it's explain how to integrate any JS code:

[Step by Step procedure to run the existing examples of D3 chart samples in Jasper Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/step-step-procedure-run-existing-examples-d3-chart-samplesthat-comes-product-6x-jasper-design)

[Custom Visualization Component v6.0.x: How to run the Samples](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-visualization-component-v60x-how-run-samples#Installing_the_samples)

[Creating your Custom Visualization Components v6.0.x](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-your-custom-visualization-components-v60x)